# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bootstrap-input-spinner')

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, typeerror, woocommerce-bookings

I'm working on an Escape room kinda website.
The theme I'm using is called ESCAPE by Themecube with Woocommerce.
The issue is I'm getting the above mentioned error while using the Woocommerce booking plugin.

The error is getting when selecting the date from the calendar(date picker is not working).

Attaching the SS of error below!

[image]

The workflow is: When we slect the date, available time slot will show and and we can book when we select the date.

But the date is not getting selected and time slot is not showing.

And this is working fine in another woocommerce theme(Storefront).

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!